# Python - Make Json objects to work concurrently through Threads?

Tags: python, json, multithreading, object, python-multithreading

What I was planning to do is to have a multiple JSON objects, for example:

```
{
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "Color": "Red",
            "house_number": "123",
            "year": "2017"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Url": "Myasdwfaesite.se",
            "My-Note": "aasfase",
            "Email": "fasfsef@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "5634543",
            "postal_code": "123445",
            "given_name": "Balling",
            "Last_name": "Calling",
            "street_address": "qwertr 123",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK",
            "phone": "65412331",
            "Color": "Blue",
            "house_number": "321",
            "year": "2018"
        }

        #Profile_2 etc etc
    }
}
```

and my plan is to make the json profile/objects to work concurrently through my code.

1. Use the profiles, between 0 - x
2. concurrently it with my code
3. When finished - exit

A more visual representation:

[image: My Thought]

*What I have done so far*

I can read one JSON object at this moment with this code:

```
with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)
```

Which gives me this output: If the first Json profile and it cant be a added another profile inside the Json else the code will not recoinze it.

An example for code that can be made out of this

```
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
```

^ This is from my code on below.

*What I expect to happened*...

What I expect to happened or want to make it to work is that with those information inside the Json file. To take those information --> Load it into the code (Below) - Make each json object profile to work concurrently with each THREAD and when everybody is done then exit pretty much. No mix between profile 1 and other or so. Every profile run for itself and execute the same way.

**CODE**

```
    with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

NameUrl = config["Url"]

myNote = config["My-Note"]

def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......
    headers = {
        'Referer': '',
        'Content-Type': ''
    }
    payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
                "email": config["Email"],
                "PersonNumber": config["PersonNumber"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                  "given_name": config["Name"],
                "Last_name": config["LastName"],

                "street_address": config["Address"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                "city": config["City"],
                "country": config["Country"],
                "email": config["Email"],
                "phone": config["Phone"],
            }

def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': NameUrl,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    payloadInfo = {
        "Information": {
            "Color": config["Color"],
            "house_number": config["houseNumber"],
            "year": config["Year"]
      }
    }    
def wipe():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main():
    time.sleep(1)

    FindName(myNote)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    try: {
        main()
    }
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wipe()
```

So easy to say. There is functions in the code such as from the beginning, `checkoutNames` and `checkoutNotes`. Basically we have different profiles. Make each profile to work concurrently with each thread for itself. Execute the code by itself and add those information from Json to the code I have entered here and vioala. That's pretty much what I dream at this moment to get it to work.

So I assume we need to make them running concurrently by multiprocess for every profile to run on their own thread without iterat between other profiles?